# Android emulator RANDOMLY doesn't start

Tags: android, emulation

After months or even a year of this, I am asking myself am I alone ? No solution ? I am on Apple M1, so starting Arm64 emulator builds, all do this:

I Start emulator it starts, then I close it start again not responding .. have to kill start it starts... Then I close then two times it wont start, and on third starts again...

Like this I live last year minimum, no update fixes it.

Is there som fix or bug report to support or anything so this get fixed eventually ?

PS: I wipe, and create new emulators all the time, nothing changes this behaviour, also I use multiple API 24, 26, 32. All do this.

Comment: The issue tracker for the emulator is at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192727 but that's read-only, if you want to file an issue you need to do it through the *Android Studio* tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708 - you might be able to find something relevant there, but honestly if you want to file a bug you'll need more information than that. It could be all kinds of things, from the current state of the emulated Android instance right down to the drivers on your computer. Error logs might be a place to start looking

Comment: @cactustictacs sure no time for that, but you know I have most common Apple MacBook Air M1 on the earth.. Millions or hundred of thousands of other android developers have it too or maybe I am in illusion but I believe that so thats why I ask..  There is nothing special about my configuration I also update and reinstall SDK and so on quite often but this persists as hell

Comment: well I mean, since it's such a popular dev choice and any widespread issue would get a lot of attention, that implies it's a problem with your machine, no? Have a look at the issue tracker to see if anyone else is running into something similar (you might see some workarounds too - they're not always exactly quick at getting around to pushing fixes) but if it's a problem with your setup, you're the only one who can solve that. Up to you if it's worth investing the time and effort though! Also you might want to try cold-booting the emulator if that's happening (maybe the snapshot is corrupt)

Comment: @cactustictacs I always cold boot.